# Fabric plugin with Android Studio won't let me "Agree"

Tags: android, android-studio, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I've installed the latest Fabric plugin into Android Studio.

Once I open the Fabric plugin, I click New App, select my application, and click next.
That then takes me to the screen to select which Kit I would like.
I click Crasylytics and select install.
From there I can see the "Agree" button, and I can click it, but nothing happens.
Has anybody else experience this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I received an update in Android Studio today that has fixed the problem.